# Previewing Images in Order with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a form in which it is possible to select images and then immediately preview all images, and flag certain images before the upload. The images are flagged using a checkbox which contain as value the name of the file, and the checkboxes are displayed on top of the images.

The images are visible, however the order in which they appear seems to be random and because of this the wrong checkbox is displayed over most of the images. Is there any way to control the order in which the images appear, or to put the correct checkbox with the correct image? [This](https://jsfiddle.net/1fc85pn6/1/) is the jQuery code that I am currently using.

```
$(function() {
  // Multiple images preview in browser
  var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

      if (input.files) {
          var filesAmount = input.files.length;

          counter=0;

          for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
              var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onload = function(event) {
                  $($.parseHTML('<div class="imagewrapper" style="position:relative">'))
                  .append($($.parseHTML('<img class="parent-width">')).attr('src', event.target.result))
                  .append($($.parseHTML("<input class='imgcheckbox' name='featured[]' value='"+input.files[counter].name+"' type='checkbox'>")))
                  .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);

                  counter++;
              }

              reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
          }
      }

  };

  $('#photoinput').on('change', function() {
      imagesPreview(this, '.photoaddview');
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you determining that the 'wrong checkbox' is placed on the images? It seems to work fine for me in your fiddle. In theory the checkbox should be entirely generic and related to the image by DOM traversal, so it doesn't matter what checkbox goes where.

Comment: The problem you're having is due to asyncronous stuff. the images don't necessarily load in order, but you're treating them as if they do

Comment: If you mean out of order as opposed to the order in which they are in the `input.files` array, that's because the `onload` event handler is called when the file is loaded, independent of `i` or the file's index within the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ad6zLfq/ : what I've done is used a LET variable, which is block scoped so your iteration variable won't ever get desynced from the image you're loading, and I've made your file loading 'reader' thing into a promise

```
function loadFile(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function() {
        resolve(event.target.result);
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  })
}

var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

  if (input.files) {
      var filesAmount = input.files.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        loadFile(input.files[i])
            .then(function(data) {
            $($.parseHTML('<div class="imagewrapper" style="position:relative">'))
                .append($($.parseHTML('<img class="parent-width">')).attr('src', data))
                .append($($.parseHTML("<input class='imgcheckbox' name='featured[]' value='"+input.files[i].name+"' type='checkbox'>")))
                .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
          })
      }
    }

  };
```

[edit]

for the record, this does NOT force the images to load in the correct order. It does, however, force the checkboxes next to the correct images, which was as you noticed a fault with the way it originally was. It's actually fairly easy to use async/await to take the example I created and ALSO make it load in order.